# Improving efficiency of my Sieve of Eratosthenes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sieve

Below is my implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes to find prime numbers up to the upper limit parameter.

Currently, my code completes in around 2 seconds when my parameter is 2,000,000. I see that I'm making one extra step by setting the numbers to nil, and then compacting rather than just deleting those numbers in one step.

How would I go about implementing this? Do you also have any other suggestions to improve the speed of my code?

```
def sieve(upper)
  i = 0
  list = (2..upper).to_a

  (2..Math.sqrt(upper)).each do |mult|
    init = mult + i
    (init..upper-1).step(mult) do |index|
      list[index] = nil
    end
    i += 1
  end
  list.compact
end
```

Comment: Imperative code is faster (`while` loops) but less readable.

Comment: please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18349336/849891) about using [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) to assess run time efficiency of programs. One point measurement says nothing. Is it `~ n^2.0`? `~ n^1.1`?

Comment: You should probably ask this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow. SO is for fixing broken stuff. CR is for improving working stuff.

Comment: This is *not* Eratosthenes Sieve, which removes only the multiples of each *prime*, i.e. the next remaining number in the list.

Comment: ok, [I measured it for you](http://ideone.com/GXkFhK) (and the code from the answer as well). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the loop where `mult` is not a prime number.

```
def sieve(upper)
  i = 0
  list = (2..upper).to_a
  (2..Math.sqrt(upper)).each do |mult|
    if list[i] #proceed only when mult is prime
      init = mult + i
      (init..upper-1).step(mult) do |index|
        list[index] = nil
      end
    end
    i += 1
  end
  list.compact
end
```

This trims down the runtime from 1.9 to 0.7 secs on my machine. I'm sure there's a lot more that can be done, though.

Comment: next improvement (though probably with less of an impact) is to start from mult^2, not from 2*mult. :) ... and skip over the evens a priori.